# how to remove dom elements

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I have an html page with multiple `<span class="classa">` but I need to remove only the ones that have an opening `{`, zero or more characters and then a closing `}` like in the example below:

```
<span class="classa">
<span class="classb">{</span>
<a href="some link" title="some title">some text</a>
<span class="classb">}</span>
</span>
```

For example if I have something like this:

```
<span class="classa">
<span class="classb">{</span>
<a href="some link" title="some title">some text</a>
<span class="classb">}</span>
</span>
```

then the entire `<span class="classa">` and it's children should be removed
but if I have this:

```
<span class="classa">
something here
<span class="classb">{</span>
or something here
<a href="some link" title="some title">some text</a>
<span class="classb">}</span>
or something here
</span>
```

then nothing should be touched.

How do I do this ? should I write a regex ?

Comment: ‘*should I write a regex ?*’ [No.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066) That is to say, don't use regex for the HTML parsing, but you could use it to match the contents.

Comment: if you have control over the generated html code why not use "classb open" and "class close" to know for sure the range of the elements which you want to remove?

Comment: @micnic unfortunately the html code is generated elsewhere

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle with the two cases inside and I will try to help you